# Excel JSON VBA Parsing - Determining if an array is empty

Tags: json, excel, vba, jscript

I am trying to parse a JSON response. I cannot use the VBA-JSON library. I need to check to see if a nested array is empty or null. I keep getting this error:

[image]

Example JSON:

```
{
"gardenAssets": [],
"gardenAssetsAlertCount": 0,
"gardenAssetsCount": 0,
"gardenAssetsErrorCount": 0,
"locationsSummaries": [
    {
        "locations": [
            {
                "auditOrder": "102",
                "code": "POT 102",
                "name": "POT 102",
                "type": "ProcessingLocation",
                "gardenAssets": [
                    {
                        "annotation": "Pallets",
                        "broker": {
                            "code": "TMTO",
                            "isOwner": null,
                            "name": null
                        },
                        "datetimeOfArrivalIngarden": 1622754283.937,
                        "id": "crusaf",
                        "isSealable": true,
                        "load": null,
                        "mastergardenCode": null,
                        "name": null,
                        "owner": {
                            "code": "SUN",
                            "isOwner": null,
                            "name": null
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "auditOrder": "103",
                "code": "POT 103",
                "description": "POT 103",
                "id": "110746",
                "name": "POT 103",
                "type": "ProcessingLocation",
                "gardenAssets": []
            },
            {
                "auditOrder": "104",
                "code": "POT 104",
                "name": "POT 104",
                "gardenAssets": [
                    {
                        "annotation": "Soil",
                        "broker": {
                            "code": "OTHR",
                            "isOwner": null,
                            "name": null
                        },
                        "datetimeOfArrivalIngarden": 1622571699.767,
                        "id": "arserana",
                        "isSealable": true,
                        "load": null,
                        "mastergardenCode": null,
                        "name": null,
                        "owner": {
                            "code": "WTR",
                            "isOwner": null,
                            "name": null
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "auditOrder": "111",
                "code": "POT 111",
                "name": "POT 111",
                "type": "ProcessingLocation",
                "gardenAssets": [
                    {
                        "annotation": null,
                        "broker": {
                            "code": "CLD",
                            "isOwner": null,
                            "name": null
                        },
                        "datetimeOfArrivalIngarden": 1622746446.932,
                        "id": "Bacrea",
                        "isSealable": true,
                        "load": null,
                        "mastergardenCode": null,
                        "name": null,
                        "owner": {
                            "code": "ICE",
                            "isOwner": null,
                            "name": null
                        },
                        "status": "EMPTY",
                        "type": "JUNK",
                        "unavailable": false,
                        "visitId": "1003768526"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "logingarden": true,
        "mastergardenCodes": [],
        "gardenCode": "FUN5"
    }
],
"offsitegardens": [],
"gardenAssetsInTransit": []}
```

Code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim S as Object, k, Ks as Object
Set S = CreateObject("ScriptControl")
S.Language = "JScript" 
S.addcode "function k(a){var k=[];for(var b in a){k.push('[\'' + b + '\']');}return k;}"

S.Eval ("var J = " & http.ResponseText)
S.Eval ("var L = J.locationsSummaries['0'].locations")
Set Ks = S.Eval("J.locationsSummaries['0'].locations")
For Each K In Ks
    If Not IsNull(S.Eval(K.gardenAssets)) = True Then
        Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = "Assets"
    End If

Next K
```

I need to pull different information out of the JSON depending on if there are any gardenAssets. But I can't seem to check to see if the array is empty or not.

Comment: You can use the JsonConverter by Tim Hall. It will create a data structure of nested dictionaries and collections. To check if there is an entry for "gardenAssets" you only need to check if the collection count has more than 0 entries. A dictionary is generated by every {} and a collection by [] https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

Comment: I cannot use the VBA-JSON library.

Comment: Because? It's a .bas file you can import as an own module to your VBA project. No need for admin rights. Or is it something lika a homework and you must use the ScriptControl object?

Comment: Requirement for project.

Comment: IIRC eval via scriptcontrol is a security risk. Please don't implement projects in this way.

Comment: What is the alternative to using eval via scriptcontrol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the length property in JScript.

```vb
    Dim S As Object
    Dim n As Integer, i As Integer, r As Long
    r = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    Set S = CreateObject("ScriptControl")
    With S
        .Language = "JScript"
        .eval "var J = " & http.ResponseText
        .eval "var A = J.locationsSummaries['0'].locations"
        For n = 1 To S.eval("A.length")
            .eval "var L = A[" & n - 1 & "]"
            For i = 1 To .eval("L.gardenAssets.length")
               Sheet1.Cells(r, 1) = .eval("L.code")
               Sheet1.Cells(r, 2) = .eval("L.gardenAssets[" & i - 1 & "].id")
               r = r + 1
            Next
        Next
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

The example JSON isn't valid. The last member of an object or the last element of an array shouldn't have a comma after it. So where you have:

```
  "broker": {
    "code": "TMTO",
    "isOwner": null,
    "name": null,
  }
```

There shouldn't be a comma after `"name": null` - there are multiple other errors like this in the example JSON.

You can use an online JSON validator (like [this one](https://jsonlint.com/)) to detect these errors. You would ideally want to fix the system that is generating this invalid JSON rather than trying to correct the issues yourself during processing

Comment: Fixed the JSON. It should be all good now. This is an example that I have modified. Sorry for the errors.